# New Dash features and Online accounts missing after 12.04 to 12.10 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, unity-dash

I performed upgrade to 12.10 from 12.04 using update-manager. Unfortunately, there was some error, because when I came back from the coffee, the screen was black.

I opened a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and `killall dpkg`, which (based on logs and `ps` outuput) seemed to be waiting for user input for configuration file update (xdg package , if I remember well).

After that, I did a `do-release-upgrade`, which seemed to work well, because I ended on a graphic session after reboot.

The problem is that some 12.10 features are missing, as Online Accounts and Dash new online results. This made me suspicious of missing packages or something like that.

Please take a look at upgrade logs and my new `dpkg --get-selections output`: https://gist.github.com/3919006

`dpkg --reconfigure -a` didn't solved the problem nor `apt-get -f install` showed any problem.

`do-release-upgrade` say my system need no news packages (even if I change `/etc/lsb-release` to 12.04)

If someone give me a `dpkg --get-selections` of a vanilla 12.10 installation, may be I can force system reconfiguration.

Comment: I was capable of get the Online Account functionality by `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-signon`, which was not installed during upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Is the package `gnome-control-center-signon` installed?

[Click here to install it](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-control-center-signon) or in a terminal window execute

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-signon
```